# NSUser Defaults not loading in a separate window from where they are saved

Tags: ios, nsuserdefaults, uitabbar

I have a Tab Bar app set up where the user selects their default branch in the first view.  In the third view, I am trying to load the user default but I keep getting a value of "null". I've tried loading

```
 NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
```

in the `viewWillAppear`, the `viewDidLoad` and nothing seems to work.  I've test the user default from the first view which will work but somehow they are loading into my other views.

Comment: Please provide the code of the working and failing cases.

Comment: @CocoaFu

NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    
    NSString *branchName = [defaults objectForKey:@"branch"];

Comment: Could you solve your problem? Did my answer help you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I was loading the defaults from the class and not the delegate